# How to Click button then the textbox1 and textbox2 will display string but different time (Delay)?

Tags: c#

I want to click button textbox1 display some string then wait 3-4 second textbox2 display.

I tried `Thread.Sleep(2000)` but click then wait all

Comment: You should not make `Thread.Sleep` on GUI thread. It will freeze your application.

Comment: Have you tried Timer?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = "Something";
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    textBox2.Text = "Something";
}
```

Follow this link for more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx